# does "in a ... fashion" mean using such a ... method?

Tags: meaning

i am learning this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.05747) in which page11 says

> Last, as classifying each pixel **in a sliding window fashion** results in
>   orders of magnitude of redundant calculation, fCNNs, as used in
>   Wolterink et al. (2016), are important aspect of an object detection
>   pipeline as well.

does "in a sliding window fashion" mean "using a sliding window method"?

Comment: Do you know what the "sliding window method" is?  I don't, but that may be part of the technical language used in object detection.

Comment: [Here's a seven year old post on sliding windows (circular buffers) in MySQL.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/20036)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does "in a sliding window fashion" mean "using a sliding window method"?

Pretty much yes.

From my understanding, "in a XYZ fashion" means "in a way (very) similar with XYZ", not necessarily "just like XYZ".

If XYZ method is directly applicable, then apply XYZ. If it is not directly applicable, then adjust XYZ in some way, to make it applicable.

---

Example:

Method XYZ = cut a loaf of bread in 3 pieces

Applied to a group of people: instead of cutting each person in pieces, group the people in 3 smaller groups.